# How to prevent/stop focus into next input text element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scenario where I need to put focus on h1 of overlay and not on next tabbable element.

Overlay is displayed after service call on blur from 1st input text.

Whenever blur event is fired focus is going to next tabbale element i.e. 2nd input text then h1 of an overlay. How can I resolve this issue?

I have a hack to put focus back on 1st input text then on h1 of overlay but I don't like this solution.

I have also tried `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation()` which don't work.

Comment: Do you mean something a bit like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/230k24y0/)? By the way, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: [Tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: well tabindex would not help me here since i have a huge form of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

try setting tabindex of input2 lower than tabindex of input1, focus on h1 on display of overlay

Comment: i tried that too then focus is going to text input 3rd then h1 of overlay.

Comment: you need to change the approach then, make service call on other event suitable to your application instead of blur event.